# If we have a state with 1/4 quadrature fluctuation, can we say it's a coherent state?

Tags: quantum-optics, coherent-states

We know that the variances of quadrature components for a coherence state satisfies:
$\langle(\Delta \hat{X}_{1})^2=\langle(\Delta \hat{X}_{2})^2 = \frac{1}{4}$

However, is its converse proposition true? That is, if we have a state with $\langle(\Delta \hat{X}_{1})^2=\langle(\Delta \hat{X}_{2})^2 = \frac{1}{4}$, can we say it is a coherent state?

Comment: Your statement is correct for Gaussian states, but you can construct a non-Gaussian state that shares a similar variance while not being a coherent state.

Comment: @RoderickLee: could you give an example? Then perhaps write it up as an answer.

Comment: I don't have an example in my mind now; I vaguely remember $e^{(\alpha a^4+\alpha^*a^{\dagger 4})}$ gives such a thing with a star-like Wigner function.

Comment: @RoderickLee : No, there are no non-Gaussian state with minimal variance. All non-Gaussian states have higher than minimal Heisenberg product.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean $\langle(\Delta \hat X)^2 \rangle = \langle(\Delta \hat P)^2 \rangle =1/4$, the converse is actually true.

If we first assume your state with minimal variance has average $\langle \hat X \rangle = \langle \hat P \rangle =0$, it is not to difficult to prove that the only state obeying these relations is the vacuum. *Hint: compute $\langle \hat n \rangle$*.

In the more general case, since the variances are defined, $\langle \hat X \rangle$ and $\langle \hat P \rangle$ being lower order moments ate also are well defined. By displacing the state by $-\langle \hat X \rangle - i\langle \hat P \rangle$, we go back to the previous restricted problem. Our state is therefore a displaced vacuum state, i.e. a coherent state.  QED